# SASS (gulp-sass) syntax problem - No output for @media with variable

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I use `gulp-sass` version `3.0.0` with `Gulp` version `3.9.1`

I can't update Gulp for the moment.

When I use variable with @media I don't have output :

```
$screen-lg: 1200px;

$under-lg: "screen and (max-width: ($screen-lg - 1px))"; 

@media #{$under-lg} {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Do you know why ? Thank you.

Comment: I believe you need to use interpolation in order to reference `$screen-lg` within a string like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the variable is inside of a string, you will have to use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) to get the result of `$screen-lg - 1px`:

```css
$screen-lg: 1200px;

$under-lg: "screen and (max-width: (#{$screen-lg - 1px}))"; 

@media #{$under-lg} {
   width: 100%;
}
```